# .NET ListView Selected issues

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, selected

I am trying to select an item in a single select `ListView`. I know you should do it by setting the `Selected` property to the item to `true`.

Everything works fine so far but when I set `Selected` to true, the `SelectedItems` collection is not update and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not fired. When manipulating the `SelectedIndices` list I get the same problem: No event, no update of the collection.

Any ideas?

---

Just to make clear, the event is fired but it happens an undefined ammount of time after `Selected` is changed. Same is for `ItemSelectedChanged` event. I am working on a WinForms app.

Comment: Is your ListView in an UpdatePanel? If not, then the change won't be apparent until a postback occurs.

Comment: It is just placed on a WinForm (this is a WinForms standalone application). I do not know about UpdatePanel, how to do a manual postback?

Comment: You should probably add WinForms to the tags, I think habitmelon was probably referring to the ASP.NET ListView control. [edit: or I could just do that myself, I didn't know I could]

Comment: Matan is right, I assumed this was a web application. My mistake.

Comment: Code that demonstrates this problem is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming you are talking about a WinForms application)

I may be wrong, but from my experience the ListView's SelectedIndexChanged event is not as reliable as you might think it would be. I think you'd better use the ItemSelectionChanged event.

Interesting link:
http://jerryandcheryl.net/jspot/2009/01/listview-selectedindexchanged-vs-itemselectionchanged/

Comment: Unfortunately the `ItemSelectionChanged` event fires also too late. I can manually call the event handler after setting `Selected` to `true` but then it will be cally twice because some time later the event is fire.

Comment: What do you mean by too late?

Comment: First I select the item (`Selected = true`), then the event handler should update the form (as it does when the user selects the item) and display some textboxes depending on the selected item. But the event handler does not do this so  I cannot access the depending textboxes after setting `Selected=True`. I assume I will workaround this logic.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your problem. You first set `Selected = true`, then the event fires up, and then in the event handler you just have to wrap your logic with a `if (e.IsSelected) { ... }`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is set `Selected = true` and the event is not fired immediatly. The code lines after ?Selected = true` need the code from the event and does not work. Then after the method is finished sometime the event is fired - but way too late.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem - I made a small test and the event fired right after I set Selected to true. My only suggestion to you now, that is other than splitting your function into 2 functions (1. until and including setting selected to true, 2. after that), is maybe to try to add your item index to the SelectedIndices collection.

Comment: I changed the layout of the dialog to avoid the problem. Nevertheless, thanks for your help! I will mark as answered for pointing to `ItemSelectionChanged`.